# How can we get username into a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

How can we use `$username`in a shorcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[education="$username"]'); ?>
```

But it doesn't work

I have a shortcode as `[education="username"]`. It works manually `[education="john-doe"]`

I want to get username into my shortcode on user profile page

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[education="username"]"); ?>
```

But it's not working. What am I missing ?

Comment: php 101 - `'`-quoted strings do NOT interpolate variables. you're sending a literal `$`, `u`, `s`, etc... to the shortcode function.

Answer (score 2):

In php, single quoted strings don't support variable interpolation. Change from single quotes to double quotes. The double quotes inside your string will need to be escaped.

Change:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[education="$username"]'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[education=\"$username\"]"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Asaph, But it's not working because of my total problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote .. Use double quote and that should work.

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[education=". $username. "]"); ?>
```

Comment: Not exactly. You'll lose the double quotes around the username once the string gets concatenated.